# Datepicker code results in drop down menu instead of calendar

Tags: html, jquery-ui, datepicker

when the following code is implemented it produces a drop down menu (when the text box is double clicked), with only five available dates, instead of producing a calendar like a regular datepicker.

```
<html>
<head>

...

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text.javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
}); </script>


...

</head>

<body>

...

<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="departuredate"/>

...

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you add the UI css link on you page? check http://jsfiddle.net/AuWmB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you loaded the jQueryUI CSS file ?

[jqueryui theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

You can try this theme :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax when calling the javascript, use / instead of .

Answer (score 1):

It may not be exactly what you need but you can use the input type="date" as per html5 standards

```
<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="departuredate">
```

Hope this helps a bit even for future references :)

Comment: You're right but you can always use a plugin such as [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to enable some of the html5 tags... That way you are still backwards compatible and keeping up to standards and semantics :)